# Why image is strectching

Tags: ios, uibutton, retina-display

I have UIbutton with image. I created small image using photoshop with png format. But when it displays in mobile i'm getting stretching. This image is stretching for iphone4 & iphone5 screen sizes. But navigation bar back button text is not stretching. See the difference between back and search button text.

[image]

[image]

```
searchbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//searchbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

searchbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(search:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//[searchbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchinside_iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];             
[searchbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchinside_iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[searchbtn setTitle:@"Search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
searchbtn.frame = CGRectMake(200, 5, 140/2, 60/2);
```

Comment: if your Image size is like:-

searchbtn.frame = CGRectMake(200 ,5 ,70 ,30);
replace with
searchbtn.frame = CGRectMake(200 ,5 ,140/2 ,60/2 );

but one thing you image size is (Width is 140 * Height is 60);
i think it's work.

Comment: @HarjotHarry: It's not working. Can you check edited code

Comment: Got the answer: [searchbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchinside_iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: setBackgroundImage: take care of this..Don't use setImage..

Comment: i know about this but this is setbackgroundImage you say the image of Button 
if you set UIButton Image you use only setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Why don't you set the frame of the button of the same dimensions as that of the image? That is the best way to ensure that your image aspect ratio does not get screwed up.